# Mandrill Authentication error for meteorjs local application

Tags: email, smtp, mailchimp, mandrill, meteor

I am trying to integrate Mandrill to send and receive emails in my application. I am doing the following from http://localhost:3000 -

Run following to add mandrill to meteor project -

```
meteor add wylio:mandrill
```

put the following in server startup -

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    return Meteor.Mandrill.config({
      username: "mandrill-user-id@gmail.com",
      key: "Valid API Key generated in Mandrill",
      password: "Valid API Key generated in Mandrill",
  });
});
```

Then call the following to send the email -

```
Meteor.Mandrill.send(
{ host:           "smtp.mandrillapp.com"
  , port:           587
  , to:             to//"customer@anydomain.com"
  , from:           from //"you@yourdomain.com"
  , subject:        "Mandrill knows Javascript!"
  , body:           "Hello from NodeJS!"
  , authentication: "LOGIN"
  , username:       "username@gmail.com"//username
  , password:       "API Key from mandrill page"//password
  }, function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
);
```

When I try sending the email, I get the following error -

```
Exception while invoking method 'sendQollMail' AuthError: Invalid login - 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password
at Object.Future.wait (/Users/priyanka/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.1qwqep8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:91:1)
at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:168:1)
at Object.Meteor.Mandrill.send (packages/wylio:mandrill/mandrill.js:12:1)
at Object.QollMailer.sendQollEmail (app/server/lib/QollMailer.js:58:21)
at [object Object].Meteor.methods.sendQollMail (app/server/lib/QollMailer.js:87:27)
at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1599:1)
at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
 at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
- - - - -
at SMTPClient._actionAUTHComplete (/Users/priyanka/.meteor/packages/email/.1.0.5.s8780m++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:826:23)
at SMTPClient._onData (/Users/priyanka/.meteor/packages/email/.1.0.5.s8780m++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:329:29)
at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
at CleartextStream.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
at _stream_readable.js:419:7
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it seems like you are missing the `return` statement on the `Meteor.Mandrill.config`

Comment: Ethaan, I tried what you are recommended but I still get the same error.

Comment: Well are you using the usernsme password and api that mandril give you?

Comment: Here is what I do - go to https://mandrillapp.com/settings/, take the SMTP Username, and SMTP Password from SMTP & API Credentials and use that in the config.

Comment: My meteor package list - meteor-platform
iron:router
meteorhacks:fast-render
jquery
jparker:crypto-md5
meteorhacks:npm
mizzao:bootstrap-3
accounts-base
accounts-ui
accounts-password
accounts-google
long:google-contacts


npm-container
mizzao:jquery-ui
mrt:ace-embed
mrt:datatables
accounts-facebook
sashko:katex
pfafman:font-awesome-4

wylio:mandrill
email

Comment: im looking into docs, but you are not using the wylo example doc

Answer (score 0):

I was doing everything correct. Except that - sometimes back I had tried integrating with mailgun (or some other service). That required setting up following env variable -

```
process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://username:password@host:port';
```

This was overriding the username/password in mandrill. Taking it out resolved the issue.